# Distribution of a stochastic process on the unit circle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am interested in the distribution of the stochastic process on the unit circle
\begin{align*}
Y_t=\exp\Big(i\mu\int_0^t e^{X_s}\text{d} s\Big) \quad ,
\end{align*}
and more specifically, in its expectation in the case of the Ornstein-Uhlenbek process
\begin{align*}
\text{d} X_t=-rX_t \text{d} t+\sigma \text{d}W_t \quad ,
\end{align*}
where $W_t$ is the Wiener process (or Brownian motion).

With the initial condition $X_0=0$, the [Feynman-Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula#Remarks) suggests to solve
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y_t|X_0=0]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty w(x,t)\text{d}x\quad ,\\
\partial_t w &=\tfrac{1}{2}\partial_x^2 w+i\mu e^{x}w \\
w(x,0) &= \delta(x)\quad .
\end{align*}
Is it the right approach? Is there a closed-form solution?

Comment: There is no stochastic PDE in this question

Comment: The PDE is written in the somewhat informal physicist way, with $W_t$ the Wiener process. I think you want to divide the second equation by $\text{d}t$ to get the stochastic PDE, and $\frac{\text{d} W_t}{\text{d} t}$ represents the Gaussian white noise.

Comment: The second equation is a stochastic ODE not PDE.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I should have written SDE.